# MySQL function IFNULL is not working correctly with Wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL Script where I am using wildcard in If Null statement. 
I am looking to show all other records regardless of field has null values in it.

```
SELECT *  FROM ABC    WHERE   (Value=1 AND        
Prefix like IFNULL(${parameter:X},'%') 
AND        
Base like IFNULL(${parameter:Y},'%')
AND        
Suffix like IFNULL(${parameter:Z},'%')
AND       
Area like IFNULL(${parameter:Ax},'%')       
);
```

I am expecting the result should show all values regardless if Area filed value is null

Comment: What does this mean?  "Customer2 filed has Null value"

Comment: there is column named'Custom2' in table acsdata where it has null values in it. so If Custom2 is null Query should fetch all other records but it is not fetching other records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `like`.  It will filter out `NULL` values in the data.  Just do:

```
WHERE (NewestVersion = 1 AND        
      (Prefix like ${param:PrefixLookup} or ${param:PrefixLookup} is null) AND
      (Base like ${param:BaseLookup} or ${param:BaseLookup} is null) AND        
      (Suffix like ${param:SuffixLookup} or ${param:SuffixLookup} is null) AND
      (Custom2 like ${param:DRELookup} or ${param:DRELookup} is null)
```

If you have empty strings, then comparisons to `NULL` will not help.  Just use:

```
WHERE (NewestVersion = 1 AND        
      (Prefix like ${param:PrefixLookup} or ${param:PrefixLookup} = '') AND
      (Base like ${param:BaseLookup} or ${param:BaseLookup} = '') AND        
      (Suffix like ${param:SuffixLookup} or ${param:SuffixLookup} = '') AND
      (Custom2 like ${param:DRELookup} or ${param:DRELookup} = '')
```

Comment: The query doesn't work. It should return all records if I don't specify any filter criteria in the text boxes e.g front end UI. Query returns no records.

Comment: @DipenShah . . . Are "unspecified values" passed in as `NULL` or as empty strings or something else?  This should be equivalent to the logic that you supplied with the exception of `NULL` handling.  (Note that I made a fix to the last condition, which might have affected your results.)

Comment: Unspecified values passed as empty string.